# Passwords obeying to regular expression rules for Plone 4.3.4

Tags: regex, passwords, plone, zope, plone-4.x

The Plone 4.3.4 release notes mention the commit `Add default Plone password policy`. I would really like to do something like, say, all (reset) passwords must be at least 8 characters, contain a lower and a upper char and also a number and a special char using a regular expression. I can only find this [bug report](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13724) and [Products.PasswordStrength](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PasswordStrength) at pypi.

The instructions for Products.PasswordStrength seem very outdated (talks about Plone 4.1 or 4.2 requirement - no word about 4.3, last release on [Plone.org](https://plone.org/products/passwordstrength) is 4 years old). Is anybody using it successfully?

Is installing Products.PasswordStrength the way to go? So that reset passwords must obey to certain regular expression rules?

Comment: The latest release on pypi is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PasswordStrength/0.3.1 from 2013-11-20. I guess you have to setup a development site and try it for your own. Since it patches some parts of PAS it could fail on Plone 4.3.x, but this should be possible to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the right tool for the job. though I am sure it has been done. I would suggest to loop over each character and check it of against a list of rules eg (in php pseudo):

```
// below rules equate to [0-9]{2,} && [A-Z]{1,} && [a-z]{2,} && [:symbol:]{2,}
rules = [num:2, upper:1, lower:2, symbol:2]

foreach(chars as char){
  if(char == [0-9]) found[num]++;
  if(char == [A-Z]) found[upper]++;
  if(char == [a-z]) found[lower]++;
  if(char == [:symbol:]) found[symbol]++;
}


foreach(rules as key => rule){
  if(found[key] < rule) return false;
}
```

For me this is the most flexible and maintainable solution to validating password complexity.

Comment: I agree, regex is not the tool for this job.  Even simple password regexes are going to be unreadable to most of your users, but some policies (for example, requiring characters from three of the four categories) will result in insanely long and repetitive regexes.  If you must implement this in-house, do yourself a favor and leave regexes out of the solution.

Comment: Frankly, this is a generic solution, but I am interested in how to do it best with Plone 4.3.4.

Comment: I know this solution doesnt address the question, but i love the readability and maintainability of this answer over a garble of regexp anyday...